# Squaring the new year

Tags: geometry, dissection

Happy new year!

You are asked to cut a rectangular strip 2015 times longer than its width into pieces that can be reassembled into a square with area equal to that of the original strip.

How many pieces do you need to cut at a minimum?

---

Hint:

> You need no more than $n+1$ pieces to reassemble a rectangle with aspect ratio (long edge length divided by short edge length) smaller than $n^2$ into a square. And $2015$ is smaller than $45^2$...

Comment: Clarification needed: does straight-line-cut mean only straight lines from paper edge to paper edge are allowed, or that each direction-change counts as a single cut? (I.e. If I zickzack through the stripe, but only in the middle of it, is this valid(but counts multiple) or not?)

Comment: @BmyGuest - The description in terms of number of cuts is distracting. I simplified the problem statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can do it in 46 pieces.

> The square root of 2015 is 44.889.  That is the size of the square you want.
>   Fill the square with horizontal stripes from the top until you have less than 2 units left in height.
>   That is 43 stripes, you have 1.889 units left vertically.
>   Then cut a diagonal along the width and cut the remaining piece in 2 as shown in the picture.
>   Left is the square assembled from a 1x2015 stripe cut in 46 pieces.
>   To better show the method, the right picture is a similar solution for a 1x20 stripe cut in 6 pieces.
>   The bottom 3 pieces can be rearranged into a 1 unit-high rectangle.
>
>  [image: 1x2015]   [image: 1x20]

Comment: 47? I come down to 65, but I might have made a mistake. See above. Also, I wonder: If *any* mis-tilt *works*, why not 0? Or does it require a *specific* tilt to be *really exact*, which would be what my solution above yields anyway...

Comment: ...ah, not *any* tilt, but the one given by exactly a strip's width over a full square's length, correct? That is a very *specific* tilt then. Nice solution. +1 from me (*Maybe edit the maths in to have it complete?*)

Comment: @FlorianF - nice, +1. However, it is possible to form a square using 46 pieces only...

Comment: I think I got it.  Need to draw the picture.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. You say to use strips until "less than 2 units left in height", which is 43 strips. Then you're adding 6 pieces which makes 49 pieces in total, not 46.

Comment: I make 43 horizontal strips, then the rest is done in 3 pieces.  The right picture is a different solution, this time for a 1x20 strip.  It has 3 horizontal strips and the rest is cut in 3 pieces.

Answer (score 6):

I might not have the optimum yet, but I think I can at least do *a lot* better than  4.4 e11...

I can do it with at maximum

> **96 pieces** (--> **65**)

---

## Proof:

As a starting point:

There is a very nice way to convert a rectangle into a square by dissection with only

> **two** cuts. (or 3 pieces)

If you do the following:

> [image: rectangle to square]

I wish I could claim having found that solution myself, but it is actually from

> [this page](http://www.math.nmsu.edu/%7Ebreakingaway/Lessons/R2S/R2S.html) 
> hosted at
>  *New Mexico State University; Department of Mathematical Sciences*

Now, this solution has a problem:

> It is only valid for rectangles where the two sides fulfil: **a < b < 2a** 
>  (So **a** is the shorter side.)

Our "starting point" is a rectangle of size **a x 2015a**.

> But we can make it to fulfil the condition! All we need is to cut stripes until **b<2a**.
>  [image]

Now we have

> a *striped* rectangle which matches the condition and used up 32 pieces(31 cuts). By applying the cutting in the first image, we will **at maximum** create 3 pieces hence we will need no more than 3 x 32 = 96 pieces to accomplish the task.

or visually:

> [image: Solution]
>  Note that X is *not* splitting the longer side of the rectangle *exactly* at 1/2, because the longer side is *not exactly* 63 but 62.96875. The solution is still valid by virtue of the general statement at the beginning of the proof.

---

---

Looking at my own answer above, I think there is a very straight-forward way to optimize the solution!

## Improved solution

Starting with the solution above:

> [image: Old solution]

It can be seen that

> The tiles of the upper half (except the very tip) can of course be merged! This reduces 62 tiles to 31 brings the solution down to 96-31 = **65** tiles.
>  [image: new]